# delete this in QTimer::singleShot

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

When processing requests in my qt server application sometimes I have to wait for a "resource" to become free. De to my understanding sleeping in the slot implementation would stop the mesasge loop, so this probably won't work as expected:

```
void MyClass::mySlot(/*some params here*/)
{
    while (resource.busy())
    {
        QThread::sleep(50);
        if (timeout)
            break;
    }
    if (!timeout) 
        doWork();
}
```

I thought of using QTimer e.g. with singleShot. My research shows, I cannot pass the parameters through the timer's signal.

My next approach would be to create an instance of a new object for each request, put the parameters to this request and use this object as recipient for the timer signal. In this slot I have to delete the request object because I haven't stored a reference to it (and don't want to).

```
void MyClass::mySlot(/*some params here*/)
{
    Request* request;
    request->setParams(...);
    request->processRequest();
}

void Request::processRequest()
{
    if (resource.busy())
    {
        // timeout missing in example/pseudocode
        QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(processRequest()));
    }
    else
    {
        doWork();
        delete this; // allowed by C++, but ugly. allowed by qt? better approach?
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach for freeing the request object or even a better approach for my problem? If not: is it valid to use `delete this;` in this context?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not duplicate (of that question, at least), this has a Qt specific answer.

Comment: I don't believe that there's something really [tag:qt] specific. `delete this` is wrong in most cases being asked for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `QObject::deleteLater()` is a very Qt specific answer to the question "is there a better approach".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: you should really stop being commenting when you lack the minimal understanding. `QObject::deleteLater()` exists for a valid reason. What it has to do with the "delete this thread", I have no clue. It is a pity that we cannot remove from that reference from the top.

Comment: @hyde: agreed, albeit it really is a duplicate as it has been asked several times. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QObject::deleteLater()`. From the [documentation :](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater)

> Schedules this object for deletion. The object will be deleted when
>   control returns to the event loop. If the event loop is not running
>   when this function is called (e.g. deleteLater() is called on an
>   object before QCoreApplication::exec()), the object will be deleted
>   once the event loop is started. If deleteLater() is called after the
>   main event loop has stopped, the object will not be deleted. Since Qt
>   4.8, if deleteLater() is called on an object that lives in a thread with no running event loop, the object will be destroyed when the
>   thread finishes. Note that entering and leaving a new event loop
>   (e.g., by opening a modal dialog) will not perform the deferred
>   deletion; for the object to be deleted, the control must return to the
>   event loop from which deleteLater() was called.